# C# failed to set property value of third party dll

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, properties, setter

I have a class defined in a third-party DLL. Reflection shows that the properties are public and has public setters as well. However, it just fails to set the property value. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: `Reflection shows`? If nothing else, use a decompiler.

Comment: Which decompiler do you recommend?

Comment: [jetbrain's dotpeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) is free

Comment: Care to show some code? Which library are you using?